# Rails + simple_form + remote_true + custom controller: how to handle different form actions for 'new' and 'edit'?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm basically following this tutorial: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails
with a variation: after creating a scaffold for 'tasks' (controller, model, views...) I've created a new controller, named '**demo**', to test the ajax way. So the 'demo' controller has the following actions: index, new_task, create_task, edit_task, update_task. Routes are also adjusted.

When I render the form (app/views/demo/_form.html.erb)

```
<%= simple_form_for @task, remote: true do |f|   %>
  <%= f.input  :description                      %>
  <%= f.input  :deadline                         %>
  <%= f.button :submit                           %>
<% end %>
```

the form 'action' will be '/tasks', that corresponds to 'controller:tasks, action:create', but that controller is for "old html" way, while the ajax stuff is in the 'demo' controller.

So, following some answers found on the web I've added the 'url' parameter:

```
<%= simple_form_for @task, remote: true, url: '/demo/create_task' do |f|   %>
  <%= f.input  :description                      %>
  <%= f.input  :deadline                         %>
  <%= f.button :submit                           %>
<% end %>
```

In this case it works well for the 'new/create' actions. But when it's time to UPDATE a model it should use '/demo/update_task' path. Which is the Rails way to handle this?

1. Add a line before the form: <% url = @task.new_record? ? "/demo/create_task" : "/demo/update_task?id=#{@task.id}" %>
2. Have two different forms, one for creating, other for editing, so 'new_task.js.erb' will point to '_form_for_creating.html.erb' and 'edit_task.js.erb' will point to the other one. Not very DRY actually.
3. Even more ugly:: have 'tasks' controller redirect to 'update_task' in 'demo' controller. I wouldn't rely on this because the tasks controller is supposed to be deleted after some testing.

Answer (score 1):

I finally chose to add a line before the form:

```
<% url = @task.new_record? ? "/demo/create_task" : "/demo/update_task?id=#{@task.id}" %>
<%= simple_form_for @task, remote: true, url: url do |f|   %>
  <%= f.input  :description                      %>
  <%= f.input  :deadline                         %>
  <%= f.button :submit                           %>
<% end %>
```

I feel it's not perfect but it works.

Of course there are a few things to adjust:

- add route `patch 'demo/update_task'`
- `update_task` in Demo controller should load all tasks after updating attributes

Comment: Nothing wrong with differentiating the url if it lets you reuse the form. I like using route helpers for simpleforms with `= simple_form_for @task, url: url_for(controller: 'demo', action: 'create'), method: 'post' do |form|`